# How do I fix this error? Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.exports.deprecate (util.js:75:1)

Tags: reactjs, filter, key, state

How do I fix this error? Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.exports.deprecate (util.js:75:1).

I was trying to used uuidv4 to generate id in order to filter list of item with id, I got an error asking me to install "util", after installing util, i now got this error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.exports.deprecate (util.js:75:1)."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
import {uuid} from 'uuidv4';
```

Use

```
import {v4} from 'uuid';
```

and call `v4()` at the place you need the unique id.

Comment: Great man. Thums up. It really helped me today.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your sample code maybe you are using a uuid() function inside a render function so this calls your uuid function again and again and this causes re-rendering of the component again and again uptil a certain amount that it reaches the maximum stack limit and throws an error
For understanding:Suppose you have a job of vegetable cutting and you are said to chop the vegetables for certain quantity but you are keeping on chopping the vegetables until it reached the ceiling and make the troublesome same does the function uuid() does if you call it like this
Similar Problem Code:Edit
soln code:
Edit
so here the parenthesis was used after the edit which was the mistake and the edit
function was called again and again and this causes a problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code - import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
instead of using - import { uuid } from "uuidv4"